# Display Custom Size Image Universal ImageLoader

Tags: android, image, universal-image-loader, coverflow

I am using Universal ImageLoader for downloading large images from server and displaying them in coverflow. Issue I am facing here is that I am unable to set custom size for my image. It just takes whole screen. For example, I am downloading image of size 500 x 1200 - and I want to display it of size 300 x 300. But it takes full display. Please help me with this issue as I am stuck for more than 3 days. Thanks.

**Code**

```
public class HomeCoverFlow {

    Context mContext;
    public CoverFlow coverFlow;
    ImageAdapter coverImageAdapter;
    ImageLoader imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
    DisplayImageOptions options;

     /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    public HomeCoverFlow(Context context)
    {
        mContext = context;
           options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
           .showImageOnLoading(R.drawable.flyer_placeholder)
           .showImageForEmptyUri(R.drawable.flyer_placeholder)
           .imageScaleType(ImageScaleType.EXACTLY)
           .cacheInMemory(true)
           .build();

         coverFlow = new CoverFlow(context);

         coverImageAdapter =  new ImageAdapter(mContext);

         coverFlow.setAdapter(coverImageAdapter);

         coverFlow.setSpacing(-25);
         coverFlow.setSelection(2, true);
         coverFlow.setAnimationDuration(1000);

         coverFlow.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);


            // HEIGHT
            coverImageAdapter.coverflowHeight = 100; //display.getHeight() / 3;

            //WIDTH
            coverImageAdapter.coverflowWidth = 100;// display.getWidth() / 2;


        }
```

A method in adapter to create item views, Here I use imageloader to download image and display

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

         FeaturedFlyerData data = (FeaturedFlyerData) getItem(position);

             if(data.flyerImage == null)
             {
                 setNewImage(position);
             }
             //see text or image
             if(data.displayImage)
             {
                 data.flyerImage.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);

                 imageLoader.displayImage(data.url, data.flyerImage, options, null);

             }


         return data.flyerImage;

}       

void setNewImage(int position)
     {
         FeaturedFlyerData data = (FeaturedFlyerData) getItem(position);

         data.flyerImage = new ImageView(mContext);
         data.flyerImage.layout(0, 10, 200,350);
         data.flyerImage.setScaleType(ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE);
         data.flyerImage.setTag(Integer.toString(position));
         data.flyerImage.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            imageClicked(Integer.parseInt(v.getTag().toString()));

        }
    });
    }

}
```

I don't know what else code snippet to provide here. Please comment if you need any further clarifications. Thanks.

Comment: data.flyerImage is an ImageView right? Did u try to set layout_height and layout_width of that ImageView?

Comment: @GlaucoNeves yes it is an imageview. I have already set in "setNewImage" method. See my edit. Am I doing it right way?

Comment: Try  data.flyerImage.getLayoutParams().height = 100;    data.flyerImage.getLayoutParams().width = 100;

Comment: @GlaucoNeves I am getting `nullpointerexception` on using this. May be it's not valid for imageviews.

Comment: Maybe this helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3144940/set-imageview-width-and-height-programmatically

Comment: Is there any reason why you don't use a xml layout to show the image?

Comment: @WarrenFaith because I am using coverflow, and it is derived from gallery widget, which just display imageview items.

Comment: @GlaucoNeves still exception is thrown.. `java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.LinearLayout$LayoutParams cannot be cast to android.widget.Gallery$LayoutParams`

Comment: Well for that particular error, you can change where you have the GalleryLayoutParams params to `LinearLayoutParams`

Comment: It worked for me. Thank you guys. I set layout params for **Gallery widget**, not **linearlayout**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using following code to display custom size images in coverflow using universal imageloader.

In constructor, set `DisplayImageOptions` as:

```
DisplayImageOptions options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
      .showImageOnLoading(R.drawable.flyer_placeholder)
      .showImageForEmptyUri(R.drawable.flyer_placeholder)
      .imageScaleType(ImageScaleType.EXACTLY)
      .cacheInMemory(true)
      .build();

//set coverflow full screen, and images size.

         coverFlow.setSpacing(-25);
         coverFlow.setAnimationDuration(1000);
         coverFlow.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
         coverFlow.setLayoutParams(new CoverFlow.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));

         // GET SCREEN SIZE
            WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
            Display display = wm.getDefaultDisplay();

            DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
            display.getMetrics(dm);

//Here I am setting image size using my custom adapter in "dp". Avoid to use pixels as things will mess up for different screen sizes

            coverImageAdapter.coverflowWidth = (int) Math.ceil(dm.widthPixels * (dm.densityDpi / 160.0));
            coverImageAdapter.coverflowHeight = (int) Math.ceil(dm.heightPixels * (dm.densityDpi / 160.0)) / 2;
```

In adapter's `setNewImage` method (called in `getView`), use **Gallery.LayoutParams**:

```
void setNewImage(int position)
 {
     FeaturedFlyerData data = (FeaturedFlyerData) getItem(position);

     data.flyerImage = new ImageView(mContext);      
     data.flyerImage.setLayoutParams(new Gallery.LayoutParams(coverflowWidth, coverflowHeight));
     data.flyerImage.setScaleType(ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE);
}
```