# Add images in random positions inside a relative layout at run time

Tags: android, android-relativelayout

Please let me know that how i can add the views like images or button inside a relative layout. But on random position , Max number of images can be 10.

Please help me out. I am attaching a view how i want the final output.

[image]

Regards
Amit Sharma

Comment: Hello Amit you can try out this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22144690/how-to-display-a-button-in-random-screen-position

Comment: Hello Deepak ,

Thanks for the answer but i need inside a layout i have tried this but it is not helpful for me thanks for the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case you should consider an [AbsoluteLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsoluteLayout.html), it would make more sense. Since this way you can randomly generate and `x` and an `y` position for each child.

There are a ton of examples on the net, [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_absolute_layout.htm) is the first one found by a Google search. The gist is something like this:

To plot something like this on the screen:

[image: AbsoluteLayout]

You can have an `AbsoluteLayout` declared like this in your activity `xml` file:

```html
<AbsoluteLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent">
   
<!--  Declare your shapes --> 

</AbsoluteLayout>
```

And then in your `Activity` or `Fragment` you will add your `Shape` objects at random positions, with something like:

```html
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
  // ...
  // Establish the working area
  DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
  getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);
  int widthArea = displayMetrics.widthPixels;
  int heightArea = displayMetrics.heightPixels;
  //Init the random generator
  Random r = new Random();
  // Then for each Shape  
  // ...
  AbsoluteLayout.LayoutParams pos = 
   (AbsoluteLayout.LayoutParams)shape.getLayoutParams();
  pos.x =  r.nextInt(widthArea);
  pos.y =  r.nextInt(heightArea);
  shape.setLayoutParams(pos);
  // ...
 }  
}
```

Comment: Thanks sir , Do you have any working sample or a chunk of code so that i can work on that.

Comment: Hi @AmitSharma, I updated my answer with some more details, hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks sir let me check , Is shape  variable is the absolute layout ?

Comment: sorry got it shape is the view that we want to add , am i rihgt ?

Comment: @AmitSharma Not sure what do you mean with: "Is shape variable is the absolute layout", but if you asked if the shaper are declared in the `xml`, that is one option, you can declare them programmatically in your `Activity` and use `addView(shape, pos);` method, to add them at runtime.

Comment: @AmitSharma Yes, `shape` is the view that you are trying to add randomly on the screen.

Comment: i have just added a answer but it is not working , Please let me know what i am doing wrong

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                     at com.abc.view.activities.splash.SplashActivity.onCreate(SplashActivity.java:46)


pos.x =  r.nextInt(widthArea);

on this line

Comment: @AmitSharma Shape should be your `view` not another `AbsoluteLayout`. `AbsoluteLayout` is a view too, but probably your shape is not an `AbsoluteLayout`. In your sample the issue is probably because you are using a `button` variable that is not initialized, instead of the `shape` variable, when creating the `pos` object.

Comment: I Got your point ,  it is working now but absolute layout has no boundries i think  so sometimge view go out of the view

Comment: @AmitSharma Yes, glad it worked. To constraint your shaped within the screen you should ensure that the random position is not to close to the edge or outside. You can use the reminder (`%`) of the division of `x` and `y` with  `widthArea` and `heightArea`.