# How can I get a view display into random position in the screen (adaptable to different screen sizes)

Tags: java, android-studio, android-studio-3.0

I already have a method to display the button in random position of the screen but it is NOT adaptable to other screen sizes. How can I do it (inside: r.nextInt()).

```
int buttonHeight;
int buttonWidth;
buttonHeight = button.getHeight();
buttonWidth = button.getWidth();
int xLeft = r.nextInt(480 - buttonHeight);
int yUp = r.nextInt(500 - buttonWidth);
int xRight = r.nextInt(670 + buttonHeight);
int yDown = r.nextInt(1400 + buttonWidth);

button.setX(xLeft);
button.setY(yUp);
button.setX(xRight);
button.setY(yDown);
```

I just want the random number to be adaptable to every screen size.

Comment: Possible solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22144690/how-to-display-a-button-in-random-screen-position

Comment: actually almost worked, the only problem is that it gets off the screen sometimes. I don´t why.

Comment: See my answer below

Answer (score 0):

Android coordinates are based on the view's top left corner. So the x and y values you feed to the view are actually x and y of the view's top left corner. Try limit the `nextInt()`'s argument to something like, `random.nextInt(maxScreenWidth - buttonWidth)` and `random.nextInt(maxScreenHeight-buttonHeight)` and assign these coordinates to your button's x and y.