# Change height of image button through code in android Studio

Tags: android

I am working in Android studio and using TableLayout. i want to display small imageButtons. and height of each button can be changed programmatically. I tried my best. but does not change the height of imageButton, Please anyone help me, what changes can i make in this code. thanks

```
 public void settable() {
        index = 0;

        LinearLayout le = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.onofffbutton);
        float height = le.getHeight();
        height= height/9.0f;

        for (int a = 0; a < maxrow; a++) {
            TableRow row = new TableRow(this);

            for (int b = 0; b < col; b++) {
                location[a][b] = new ImageView(this);
                /*LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(50, 50);
                location[a][b].setLayoutParams(layoutParams);*/
                if (isOn[a][b]) {
                    location[a][b].setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.box1);
                } else {
                    location[a][b].setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.box);
                }
                location[a][b].setMaxHeight(height);

                location[a][b].setOnClickListener(Onclick);
                location[a][b].setId(index++);
                row.addView(location[a][b]);
            }
            tableLayout.addView(row, a);
        }
    }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Set ImageView width and height programmatically?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3144940/set-imageview-width-and-height-programmatically)