# How to change the height of an image_view at runtime

Tags: android

I tried `IMAGEVIEW.getLayoutParams().height = 200`. But it is not changing correctly. Is there any other possible way, please give suggestion.

Comment: getLayoutParams() not setLayoutParams()

Comment: You can use `DisplayMetrics` logic . Why using `Hard-Coded` Value ?

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3144940/set-imageview-width-and-height-programmatically

Answer (score 2):

use this

```
 LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(200, 200);
    yourImageView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
_image_view.getLayoutParams().height = 30;
```

Hope this helps.

**Very Important.**

If you're setting the height after the layout has already been 'laid out',
make sure you also call this :

```
_image_view.requestLayout()
```

Comment: i tried this. but it is not working. thanks for your reply.

Comment: Dear , its working well in my case.  ImageView im = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        im.getLayoutParams().height = 130;

Answer (score 1):

```
 ImageView mImageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image_view);
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(100, 100); // Paramters are (width, height) in pixels
            mImageView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
```

If you want multiple resolution compatibility,

```
 LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams((int)(getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.image_with)),
                (int) getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.image_height));
```

dimens.xml under resource

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <dimen name="image_with">100dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="image_height">100dp</dimen>
</resources>
```

Answer (score 0):

If your imageview already shows the image,

Call:

```
image_view.requestLayout();
```

Answer (score 0):

At First Check **[Set ImageView width and height programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3144940/set-imageview-width-and-height-programmatically)**

You can try with **DisplayMetrics** Logic .Its more perfect .

> A structure describing general information about a display, such as
>   its size, density, and font scaling.

```
   DisplayMetrics metrics = getResources().getDisplayMetrics();

   int DeviceTotalWidth = metrics.widthPixels;
   int DeviceTotalHeight = metrics.heightPixels;

   image_view.getLayoutParams().height= (int) (DeviceTotalHeight*5.25/100); // You can change from here
```

**Another Way**

```
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new  LinearLayout.LayoutParams(200, 200);
    IMAGEVIEW.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
```