# How to change the image size added programmatically

Tags: java, android

I have a `LinearLayout` which I add images when i click a button, I was trying to use `LayoutParams`to change the width and height because doesn't fit as at should, and I always got a null reference, the problem is I can't make any reference because is not a static `ImageView`.

This is how I add images inside of `LinearLayout` :

```
public void AddNewImages(Context context,Bitmap bitmap){
    ImageView img = new ImageView(context);
    img.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
    img.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    linearImages.addView(img);
    bitmapArray.add(bitmap);
    indexTags++;
}
```

XML :

```
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:id="@+id/linearImages"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <Button
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:id="@+id/add_btn"
                android:text="Add"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </HorizontalScrollView>
```

Comment: get imageview from linearImages child

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you have to find the Imageview which you added in linearlayout and set the size
i.e

```
for(int i=0;i<linearImages.getChildCount();i++)
{
    ImageView image=(ImageView)linearImages.getChildAt(i);
    image.getLayoutParams().height=100;
    image.getLayoutParams().width=100;
}
```

Comment: where should I put this for? right after `indexTags++;` ? I tried and my app crash without give any error

Answer (score 0):

```
ImageView imgae = (ImageView) linearImages.getChildAt(0); // For first image
```

and then set `LayoutParam`.

Answer (score 0):

You are creating ImageView dynamically so you have to first set layoutParameters for it and then you can set height and width of imageview. Refer this [NullPointerException while setting LayoutParams](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36340268/nullpointerexception-while-setting-layoutparams) question