# How to change the ImageView Height an Width

Tags: android, imageview

I have created a new `ImageView` by Java code, but when I try to set height using `setMaxHeight`, its not working. Can someone help me to change the height of that ImageView?

```
ImageView i = new ImageView(MainActivity.this);
i.setImageResource(R.drawable.red);
i.setMaxWidth(50);
i.setMaxHeight(50);
ll.addView(i);
```

Comment: search on google. too old question

Comment: [Set ImageView width and height programmatically?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3144940/set-imageview-width-and-height-programmatically)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this code to set width and height.

```
ImageView iv = new ImageView(context);
int width = 60;
int height = 60;
LinearLayout.LayoutParams parms = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(width,height);
iv.setLayoutParams(parms);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
 i.getLayoutParams().height = 20;
```

Comment: all credit goes to owner http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3144940/set-imageview-width-and-height-programmatically

Answer (score 1):

The easy way is to set the size programatically like that :

```
i.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(width, height));
```

if you want to change dp to pixel you can use this Code:

```
public static float pxFromDp(final Context context, final float dp) {
    return dp * context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
}

i.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(pxFromDp(this, 50), pxFromDp(this, 50)));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
your_image_view.getLayoutParams().width = 100;**
your_image_view.getLayoutParams().height = 100;**
```

you found your answer [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3144940/set-imageview-width-and-height-programmatically)

Hope this will helps you bro