# How to change imageview size on button click

Tags: java, android, xml

I am working on an app which displays an image in the center.
The xml code of the ImageView is below

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/e_sym"
    android:layout_width="300px"
    android:layout_height="300px"
    android:rotation="0"
    android:contentDescription="@string/symbol_e"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.499"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.498"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/symbol_e" />
```

I want to change the height and width from the java program on click of button.

```
decr.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        //code to change height and width values of the ImageView
    }
});
```

**The size has to be in pixel format**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Set ImageView width and height programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3144940/set-imageview-width-and-height-programmatically)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you just have to mention the width and the height of the imageView in LayoutParams.

```
decr.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        //code to change height and width values of the ImageView

        imageView.getLayoutParams().height = 50; //can change the size according to you requirements
        imageView.getLayoutParams().width = 50; //--
        imageView.requestLayout()
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE);

    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the `height` and `width` in `LayoutParams`. Check below:

```
decr.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        //code to change height and width values of the ImageView

        imageView.getLayoutParams().height = 20;
        imageView.getLayoutParams().width = 20;
        imageView.requestLayout()
    }
});
```

Comment: @UzairMukadam, What's the problem? Why you reverse? Is there any problem in my answer? Point out my fault so that i can correct myself. Thanks