# What is the relation between "dp" and int in Android Studio?

Tags: android, textview, imageview

We all know that a TextView has an attribute "textSize", whose unit varies from "dp" to "sp".

But one day when I am searching a question "[Set ImageView width and height programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3144940/set-imageview-width-and-height-programmatically)", I find the highest voted answer wrote: `image_view.getLayoutParams().height = 20;`

Actually I want to programmingly set an ImageView's height as tall as a TextView, but the textSize of the TextView is 20dp, and the height of the ImageView is an int, 20.

So what is the relation between "dp" and "int" ? How can I convert one to another ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By programmatically when you set view's width, the height it actually takes **pixel** as an integer value. So when you set `image_view.getLayoutParams().height = 20;` that means it takes **20 pixel**. But you can also set dp in width and height by converting **dp** to **pixel** . You can convert by this

```
final float scale = getContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
int pixels = (int) (dps * scale + 0.5f);
```

Here **dps** your actual **dp** and its converting pixel for setting width and height.

Comment: That's clear! But I have one more question: why you "+0.5f" at last?

Comment: It is actually a formula to convert dp to the pixel.  And I can say that the +0.5f, the purpose is to round to the nearest pixel.  For more information, you can visit https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screendensities

Comment: Well, that's a bit complicated to me, and maybe I need more time to understand them and ask another question some other days. But I do figure out the answer of the original question, so thank you very much!