# Update Image width and Margins programmatically

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, rx-kotlin, data-class

I have a drawable that's being displayed in a layout. The drawable has default properties such as color and width. I'm creating a data class to be able to update those when the recycler view is created. The part that fills in the color in the middle is working. But I'm stuck on how to actually update the drawable width and the ImageView margins from the viewHolder.

mydrawable.xml

The layout file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/rect_outline"
        android:src="@drawable/mydrawable"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginStart="12dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="12dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

The data class

```
data class ImageData(
    val c: String
    val width: Int
    val marginLeft : Int
```

)

MyViewHoler.kt

```
internal class MyViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
fun bind(item: ImageData) {
   itemView.rect_outline.setColorFilter(Color.parseColor(item.c))

}
```

}

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Set ImageView width and height programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3144940/set-imageview-width-and-height-programmatically)

Comment: No, unfortunately, it doesn't. I'm not trying to change the Imageview width only it's margins.  On the other hand, I do want to update the drawable width

Answer (score 0):

first put this into your xml image view component

```
android:scaleType="fitCenter"
```

my sugest is use scale with animation to get a good looking for the user

```
imageView.animate()
                    .scaleX(scaleValue)
                    .scaleY(scaleValue)
                    .setDuration(MOVING_ANIMATION_DURATION)
                    .start()
imageView.invalidate()
```

but you can set a new layout params like:

```
val l =  imageView.layoutParams
            l.height =  value
            l.width = value
            imageView.layoutParams = l
```

you can do this way too

```
    val params = LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
            )
            params.setMargins(0, 20, 0, 40)
            params.height = 1
            params. width = 1
            imageView.layoutParams = params
```

Comment: can the second way be used to target the drawable resource?

Comment: if you set the drawable into imageview and programmatically do what you wanna do after , the drawable will behave the way what you want

Comment: @PizzaParty123 sorry put this into your xml android:scaleType="fitCenter" imageview